# Id property not populated

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an identity mapping like so:

```
Id(x => x.GuidId).Column("GuidId")
    .GeneratedBy.GuidComb().UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);
```

When I retrieve an object from the database, the GuidId property of my object is Guid.Empty, not the actual Guid (the property in the class is of type System.Guid).  However, all of the other properties in the object are populated just fine.

The database field's data type (SQL Server 2005) is uniqueidentifier, and marked as RowGuid.

The application that is connecting to the database is a VB.NET Web Site project (not a "Web Application" or "MVC Web Application" - just a regular "Web Site" project).  I open the NHibernate session through a custom HttpModule.  Here is the HttpModule:

```
public class NHibernateModule : System.Web.IHttpModule
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;
    public static ISession Session;
    private static FluentConfiguration Configuration;

    static NHibernateModule() {
        if (Configuration == null) {
            string connectionString = cfg.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDatabase"].ConnectionString;

            Configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(cs => cs.Is(connectionString)))
                .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.Properties.Add("current_session_context_class", "web"))
                .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<LeadMap>().ExportTo("C:\\Mappings"));
        }

        SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.BeginRequest += delegate {
            Session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(Session);
        };

        context.EndRequest += delegate {
            CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
        };
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Session.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The strangest part of all, is that from my unit test project, the GuidId property is returned as I would expect.  I even rigged it to go for the exact row in the exact database as the web site was hitting.  The only differences I can think of between the two projects are

1. The unit test project is in C#
2. Something with the way the session is managed between the HttpModule and my unit tests

The configuration for the unit tests is as follows:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(cs => cs.Is(connectionString)))
    .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<LeadDetailMap>());
```

I am fresh out of ideas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when in the mapping attribute Name was not set. You can try to save your fluent mappings into Xmls and check them.

Comment: Thanks for the export tip (I'm new to the NHibernate world).

Unfortunately, the mappings look identical between the two projects.  Here's the GuidId column:

    <id name="GuidId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="GuidId" />
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>

Still at a loss.